# Uncaught ReferenceError: signals is not defined

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-2.1

Hi I am adding a js file to get a push slide in menu so I can change the country which is working here http://kaiel.fr/shopnew/kaielf.html

But in magento 2.1 http://kaiel.fr/shopnew/ it does not work. I get in chrome `Uncaught ReferenceError: signals is not defined` flang.js line 3065 which is

```
signals: new signals(),
```

In my `requirejs-config.js` I put

```
var config = {
paths: {
        'footerlang': 'js/flang'
            },
shim: {
                    'flang': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
}
```

};

And in my `footer.phtml` I put

```
<script type="text/javascript">require(['js/flang']);</script>
```

Plus I get this error in chrome

```
require.js:1895 GET http://kaiel.fr/shopnew/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/fr_FR/signals.js
```

I don't have this file

Please help me

Comment: Tried to run static content deploy?

Comment: I am in developer mode so I think there is no need to do that